# MGF of distribution with PDF $\frac12 e^x\mathbf 1_{x<0}+e^{-2x}\mathbf 1_{x > 0}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

To derive moment generating function(mgf) of $f(x) = 1/2 e^x $ when $x<0$ and $= e^{-2x}$ when $x > 0$,

Since mgf $M(t) = E(e^{tx})$, we get

$E(e^{tx}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\cdot f(e^{tx})dx = \int_0^\infty e^{tx}\cdot e^{-2e^{tx}} + \int_{-\infty}^0e^{tx}\cdot {1\over 2}e^{e^{tx}}$

But is there any way to integrte into more simple format?

Comment: Actually $\mathbb E[e^{tx}] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} f(x) dx$, which is a much simpler integral!

Comment: @KennyWong but I had learned the def of $\Bbb E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx$. From this, isn't my application of the def correct?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Let's look at discrete random variables rather than continuous random variables for a moment, so that we can better use our intuition. If $X$ takes value $0$ with probability $1/3$ and takes the value $1$ with probability $2/3$, how would you write down a formula for the expected value of $X^2$? (I'm asking what your **intuition** tells you!)

Comment: The error is that you have got the definition wrong. If $X$ is a random variable with $f$ its pdf, and if $g$ is a function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)f(x)dx$ exists, then $E[g(X)] := \int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)f(x)dx$.

Comment: @YngwieMalmsteen thx. That def is correct and mine was not.

Comment: @Beverlie, No problem then you solved your question :)

Answer (score 0):

$$M(t) = E(e^{tx}) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}e^{tx}\cdot 0.5e^{-x}dx + \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{tx}e^{-2x}dx = \frac{0.5}{t-1} + \frac{1}{2-t}$$

Note, that $t>1$ for the first integral to exist and $t<2$ for the second integral to exist. Therefore the mgf exists for $t \in (1,2)$.